# Keyword Specific VS Non-Specific Targeting in SEO

Tags: seo

Does Keyword specific brings better value in SEO compare to non-specific targeting?

Example:

```
<a href="www.companyA.com">Website Design</a>
<a href="www.companyB.com">Website Design - Company B</a>
<a href="www.companyC.com">Website Design & Mobile Apps Development</a>
```

Based on 3 example above, which one is the best that will bring best value in SEO?

Comment: All examples are bad... Google dislikes over optimised anchors and you'd be better of using `<a href="http://www.companyA.com">Company Name</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Commenter bybe has it right - the best anchor text for your company is your company name.  This is **especially** true if you're using it as part of a pro-active campaign to build backlinks, or if it's going to be reused programmatically.

The common use case for web design companies is attributing their work. Lots of web design companies put links on sites they've built back to their own domain. As the number of domains grow, and the number of pages on those domains grow, you end up with LOTS of repeated anchor text.

If that repeated anchor text is your company name, that's fine.

If that repeated anchor text is "keyword rich" (and all your examples A, B & C qualify), then you put your domain at risk of penalization for manipulative linking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which words you want to optimize for SEO. If you target "Website Design" as keywords, the best link for SEO is the first one.

Indeed, in the others, you have more words; therefore the SEO value of the words "Website Design" in the anchor text is diluted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if now got someone search for mobile app development, will the third one appear and the first one is not in the list?

Comment: If the words "mobile apps development" are present in your site, your site can get listed by Google for these search terms. And maybe your site will rank higher if you choose the third link instead of choosing the first one.

Comment: Keep in mind that conversational links tend to perform better only because they appear more organic in nature. As well, if you are embarking on a back link campaign, then it is best *NOT TO* repeat or over optimize your links though certainly a healthy portion of your links should be appropriately targeted. If you examine almost anyones link profile and look specifically at organic links, you will find that they are simple in language and not heavily targeted. You can have a targeted back link strategy that takes advantage of these traits if planned well.